# What's a better way to increase insertion efficiency without creating an oversized cache buffer?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

By setting a unique index on items in a mongodb collection, then inserting the values within a `try, catch` I realize we can avoid inserting duplicate indexes effectively. However, if you're going for efficiency and setting a very high number of values per second, it's faster to store the paths to a dictionary and check for duplicates like this rather than wait for the database to reject your insertion attempt (even on a locally run database):

```
if (!cache[path]) {
  cache[path] = true;
  promises.push(this.db.collection(collection).insertOne({
    path,
    data
  }).catch(err => {}));
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the `cache` dictionary builds up potentially infinite numbers of properties and my program slows down with the read time. Let's say I use a `WeakMap` instead of an array so we keep an O(1) read time, but that still leaves us with the issue of the memory used by node being potentially infinite. What's a better way to handle this?

Comment: If the idea is to just reduce the number of rejections from the server and not be absolutely sure there are none, you could use an LRU structure for the cache, i.e. only keep the latest _N_ entries... or maybe just clean the cache every _T_ seconds and hope for the best?

Comment: @AKX yeah I was thinkin somethin like that.

Comment: @AKX maintaining an LRU is not exactly a lightning fast operation on a dictionary of scale, you'd have to maintain a secondary array to keep track of what order the properties got inserted in, run Object.values, etc. Then again maybe with a weakMap that's not true. Ah yeah, WeakMap is the solution because iirc it even keeps track of the order the properties were inserted in.

Comment: Use bulk inserts (with or without application level caching of what exists in the database).

Comment: @D.SM Yeah I found that it was massively faster. But it looks like I can't bulk update batches of documents based on different indexes, only based on one selection criteria :/ I havent fully explored if `bulkWrite` can bulk update by selecting individual ids though, whether its even faster than doing them one by one

Comment: Different conditions must be given as separate operations but there is still value in batching the operations in one round-trip to the database.

Comment: @D.SM Appreciate the info